# Trouble visualizing recursion in the Merge Two Sorted List problem

Tags: recursion, data-structures, linked-list

Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

Solution: https://repl.it/@Stylebender/HatefulAliceblueTransversal#index.js

My understanding is that we eventually hit base case and return 4 since L2 will be null.

I'm just a bit confused as to what happens and grateful if someone could describe the flow when the call stack starts popping and how we ultimately get one merged list?

Answer (score 1):

The base case returns [4] and not a number, I think. Otherwise, the types would be wrong. But I don't speak JavaScript, so I might be wrong. Anyway, it doesn't matter for the question, I think.

I don't know how helpful it is, but you can think about recursion as doing one thing going down and another going up, where what you have to do when you go up is what is stored on the stack. (With tail-recursion, you avoid the second step, so that is usually the better approach, but it is not always easy to achieve).

When you merge the lists in this way, you start with lists `[1, 2, 4]` and `[1, 3, 4]`, and going down, you pick which branch to recurse on. The call stack remembers what the front of the lists are at each level, in the local variables, and it remembers which branch you took by saving the instruction ponter.

```
state: [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4]. => not 1 < 1 so go right, remember (right)
state: [1, 2, 4], [3, 4].    => 1 < 1 so go left, remember      (left)
state: [2, 4], [3, 4].       => 2 < 3 so go left, remember.     (left)
state: [4], [3, 4]           => not 4 < 3 so go right, remember (right)
state: [4], [4]              => not 4 < 4 so go right, remember (right)
state: [4], []               => base case, return [4]
```

If we just look at the branches we took, our stack is `[(right); (left); (left); (right), (right)]`. We also have the lists at each level in `l1` and `l2`, but you should only think of those as the head element of the lists. We are going to modify the lists as we return. The operations we do will modify the `.next` references in the lists, so anything to the right of the first element doesn't matter as we return. When we change a `.next` reference going up from the recursion, we change the state of the lists in the earlier calls. The front elements remain, though. So I will remove all but the first elements now, and flip the order, so we can go through the stack from top to bottom. Hope this isn't confusing.

```
state 0: [4],  [] => base case, return [4]
state 1: [4], [4] => (right)
state 2: [4], [3] => (right)
state 3: [2], [3] => (left)
state 4: [1], [3] => (left)
state 5: [1], [1] => (right)
```

so we start with a return value of `[4]` from the base case, and we are in state 1 in the right branch. Here, we put the returned list, `[4]`, into the next value of `l2`, so `l2` changes from `[4]` to `[4, 4]` and we return.

```
state 1: [4], [4] => return [4, 4]
state 2: [4], [3] => (right)
state 3: [2], [3] => (left)
state 4: [1], [3] => (left)
state 5: [1], [1] => (right)
```

that takes us to state 2, where we are in the right branch, with the returned list `[4, 4]` and 3 in `l2`. Actually, since we modified `l2` before we returned it already has the remaining list, so it is really `[3, 4, 4]`. Not that it matters, because we set `l2.next` to `[4, 4]` so now it definitely is. And we return it.

```
state 2: [4], [3] => return [3, 4, 4]
state 3: [2], [3] => (left)
state 4: [1], [3] => (left)
state 5: [1], [1] => (right)
```

We go to state 3 where we are in the left branch. We got the list `[3, 4, 4]` from the recursive call (it is also `l2`, because it was `l2.next` we modified, and the `[3]` in the state should really be `[3, 4, 4]`. That is what `l2` holds right now). Since we are in the left branch, we update `l1`'s `.next`, so `l1` becomes `[2, 3, 4, 4]` (the 2 is its current head and the rest is what we returned). Again, `l1` actually held more values, we never modified it when we went down the recursion, but it is only the head that matters. After we write to `l1.next` those previous values are gone in any case. So now `l1 = [2, 3, 4, 4]` and `l2 = [3, 4, 4]` if you want to be strict about it, but the only thing that matters is what their heads are as we move up, and that we return `[2, 3, 4, 4]` from the recursion.

```
state 3: [2], [3] => [2, 3, 4, 4]
state 4: [1], [3] => (left)
state 5: [1], [1] => (right)
```

In state 4, the heads of `l1` and `l2` are 1 and 3, respectively, and we have `[2, 3, 4, 4]` from the recursion. The actual values are `l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]` and `l2 = [3, 4, 4]`, but again, only the heads matter. We are in a left branch, so we should put the returned value, `[2, 3, 4, 4]` in `l1`'s `.next`, which gives us `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]` (which is what we had already, but that doesn't matter...).

```
state 4: [1], [3] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
state 5: [1], [1] => (right)
```

In state 5, we went right, so we should add the returned value to `l2.next`, which changes `l2` to `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]` because the head was 1. That is the list we return.

The thing that is confusing with this implementation is that you are modifying the lists as you return from the recursion. As we return, `l1` and `l2` refers to the head of modified lists. We only need the head for the recursion to work, but we have the entire lists. There is nothing wrong with that, but the lists should be considered lost to the world after you call merge. You will have changed them as a side-effect. If you build new links as you return from the recursion, you can avoid that. That will also make it easier to make a tail-recursive version if you prepend to an accumulator that you then reverse at the end.

I don't know if that helps, but I think it is the best that I can do this early in the morning...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! Will go through it later.

Comment: I hope it is at least a little useful.

Comment: Yes looks pretty helpful but quite complicated haha especially for someone who prefers iteration over recursion

Comment: It is pretty easy to get an iterative merge if that is what you want. It won't be much more complicated and most certainly faster than this non-tail-recursive version.